# Dynamic linq expression expected

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Dynamic links

```
IQueryable<DataRow> queryable = excelTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsQueryable().Where("[First Name] == null");
```

error : Expression expected.

what should i do

Comment: Why did you this linq-to-sql? This doesn't look like that. Also, the `AsQueryable()` seems pointless in your query.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to use dynamic LINQ. Do you have references to the proper assembly and the correct `using`?